# Titan extruder retraction noise

Tags: extruder, stepper-driver, motor, retraction, e3d-titan

I am experiencing some retraction noises with my Titan Extruder. At first the noise was more of a clicking noise, and the gear was skipping. I didn't feel any backlash with my finger but I still followed the official troubleshooting guide on backlash and the noise has changed to some sort of buzzing, with print quality noticeably improving.

I should mention I recently upgraded my stepper drivers to TMC2208, extruder set to 1.31V. May be too much but I know the extruder motor needs a whole lot of torque, either way it doesn't run too hot so I'm keeping that for now. (If anyone knows how warm should a motor feel during normal operation let me know.)

I have two videos of the noise before and the noise after. I can't tell where this noise is coming from, I have never heard weird motor noises before so I can't tell if it's still the extruder or if it's the motor. I can't tell if it's normal.

I tried feeding filament in and out with GCode to find out the feedrate at which the noise goes away, and I found that anything above F2200 makes it do this noise, otherwise it's a pretty normal noise.

Before:

After:

Comment: I am new to 3d-Printing and am having my printer start to make the noise you display in the after video. If I understand your post, your saying that this is a normal noise and shouldn't be worried about? really appreciate any input! thanks!

Comment: Oh, oh no, do worry about this. My buzzing eventually was gone and never came back, returned to just clicking. And retractions started failing 90% of the time causing terrible layer defects and lack of precision. E3D refused to acknowledge this and claimed I was doing everything wrong, but I think they just didn't want to refund the defective extruder. Overall it's a poor design, it relies on the mounting bracket to properly assemble, even.

Switching to the standard extruder (which is cheap and crappy) yielded accurate printing again.

All of this was caused by stubborn gear backlash.

Comment: The question has been reverted to the original edited question, please answer in a separate answer below. Please try to be objective so that is doesn't come over as a rant.

Comment: @GuidoBelluomo It might be that a different current limit was needed for the extruder motor.

Comment: @Andrew Morton It was not skipping steps. The gears were skipping, backlash was confirmed by doing the gear wiggle test suggested by E3D.

Answer (score 1):

After several email exchanges with the customer support, I was not able to find an answer. It was stated that it may have been my assembly and/or extruder mount, but I'm strongly against that after so many times reassembling.

Gear backlash ended up becoming permanent.

I ended up switching over to something else with a more self-sufficient design and less variables.